# Automated way to gather request URL of generated form data; for a webspider

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a .csv file I generated that contains different location search pages.
ie: [Search page 1](http://www.lkqpickyourpart.com/locations/LKQ_Pick_Your_Part_-_Raleigh-168/), [Search page 2](http://www.lkqpickyourpart.com/locations/LKQ_Pick_Your_Part_-_Durham-142/), etc.

With only one search page if I wanted the Request Url I would easily just look at the XHR feed in Chrome Dev to find it, then just have a variable string replace where the keyword was located to get the request url for different keywords within that given location page. I would know the "Store" number and the "carbuyYardCode" number already because its only one location.
Here is what my code for my spider that does this looks like:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import scrapy
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

keyword = raw_input('Keyword: ')
url = 'http://www.lkqpickyourpart.com/DesktopModules/pyp_vehicleInventory/getVehicleInventory.aspx?store=224&page=0&filter=%s&sp=&cl=&carbuyYardCode=1224&pageSize=1000&language=en-US' % (keyword,)
class Cars(scrapy.Item):
    Make = scrapy.Field()
    Model = scrapy.Field()
    Year = scrapy.Field()
    Entered_Yard = scrapy.Field()
    Section = scrapy.Field()
    Color = scrapy.Field()
    Picture = scrapy.Field()


class LkqSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lkq"
    allowed_domains = ["lkqpickyourpart.com"]
    start_urls = (
    url,
)

    def parse(self, response):

        picture = response.xpath('//@href').extract()
        section_color = response.xpath('//div[@class="pypvi_notes"]/p/text()').extract()
        info = response.xpath('//td["pypvi_make"]/text()').extract()
        for element in range(0, len(info), 4):
            item = Cars()
            item["Make"] = info[element]
            item["Model"] = info[element + 1]
            item["Year"] = info[element + 2]
            item["Entered_Yard"] = info[element + 3]
            item["Section"] = section_color.pop(
            0).replace("Section:", "").strip()
            item["Color"] = section_color.pop(0).replace("Color:", "").strip()
            item["Picture"] = picture.pop(0)           
            yield item
```

The request urls for all the search pages in my .csv file are all are exactly the same, and the main differentiator are the "Store" number and the "carbuyYardCode" number near the end of the URL. The big question is: is there a way in an automated fashion to somehow obtain these two sets of identification numbers for each location's request url so I could execute my spider across all of them for a given keyword. Or is manually looking in Chrome Dev XHR feed for each request URL the only way to find the link to extract these numbers from?

Thanks alot pretty new to this Scrapy thing,
Daniel